# Unable to click on docusign envelope sign button

Tags: java, selenium, docusignapi

I need help, I am trying to click on the sign button on docusign envelope page (using selenium java) but doesn't seems to be working. I have used the driver.switchTo.frame() as advised in my earlier post clicking on continue on the docusign page it worked fine but not sure how to handle the docusign envelope as i have used the same principle using frame() and clicking on the sign button but no luck. I can able to click on the outer part of envelope but not on the envelope. Really Appreciate any advise. Many Thanks

Comment: Hi Kumar, not to worry, Please share your code.

Comment: Hi Kishan, Thanks please find below code driver.switchTo().frame( driver.findElement( By.xpath("//*[@id='999']")));
  driver.findElement(By.id("action-bar-btn-continue")).click();
  Thread.sleep(15000);
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
  driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='container']")));
  driver.findElement(By.id("ds_hldrBdy_895626d9-1f49-47c0-ace0-f6f99a144a43")).click();

Comment: Your switch to frame isn't correct i guess. Please share me the class code so that i can put it in my eclipse and debug it. Please .

Comment: Hi Kishan, appreciate your help. Actually the data is confidential unfortunately i cannot able to share the code. Is there any other alternative ? Thanks

Comment: try replicating the above issue on a public URL

Comment: Then please try to refer this. I cannot do anything without code. Your problem is switching to frameonly.
 https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-work-with-iframes-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Hi Kishan, can you please provide me your email id i can send you my sample code ??